# How can I replicate this shadow + offset in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to replicate a component written in UIKit using SwiftUI

It is a 'shadowed card container' that looks like this -

[image: expected]

You see the shadow effect has an offset and height value to it

Trying to create this in SwiftUI I cannot get it quite right -

[image: result]

The UIKit view is handled via an extension -

```
public extension UIView {
    func addShadow(offset: CGSize = .init(width: 0, height: 3), color: UIColor = .init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.16), radius: CGFloat = 2, opacity: Float = 1) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowOffset = offset
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

On a view -

```
public class CardContainerView: UIView {
    
    private var didlLayoutSubviews = false
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureUI()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
    
    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard !didlLayoutSubviews else { return }
        didlLayoutSubviews = true
        addShadow(
            offset: .init(width: 0, height: 3),
            color: .init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.16),
            radius: 2
        )
    }
}

private extension CardContainerView {
    func configureUI() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 12
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

I have tried this in SwiftUI and come up with -

```
public struct CardView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    
    private var content: () -> Content
    
    public init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack(content: content)
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color(.tertiarySystemBackground))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .shadow(
                color: Color(.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.16)),
                radius: 2
            )
    }
}
```

I cannot understand how to apply the height and offset values to the shadow in SwiftUI

Comment: .shadow(color: Color(.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.16)), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 3) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the offset values to the `x` and `y` values of the shadow.

```
VStack(content: content)
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, alignment: .top)
    .background(Color(.tertiarySystemBackground))
    .cornerRadius(12)
    .shadow(
        color: Color(.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.16)),
        radius: 2,
        y: 3 // This should give you the same effect
    )
```